# How to uppercase first char in the C input?

Tags: c

My output doesn't uppercase next argument after space-character (' ').

```
int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    int flag = OUT;
    char name[100];
    int leng = strlen(name);

    printf("Value pls: \n");
    fgets(name, 100, stdin);
    printf("%c", toupper(name[0]));

    while(name[i])
    {
        printf("%c", name[i + 1]);
        if(i == ' ')
        {
            printf("%c", toupper(name[i + 1]));
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

It's always shows somthing like this:
**Value pls:**
jon smith
Jon smith

Word "smith" is always lowercase.

Comment: `i == ' '` checks if the numerical index is a space, not if the character at that index is a space.

Comment: Your program is working properly. Check exactly what you passed to `toupper` the first char of your input, which is indeed 'J'.

Comment: I doubt that this is really the output of your program. Your are printing the first character twice - once as it is, once as toupper. I bet you don't get "Jon" after you Input "jon".

Comment: @WernerHenze `Jjon Ssmith` makes sense for the output.

Comment: Sry, I have lost i+1

Comment: Your loop will print the string terminator.

Comment: @Alex Now you get `jJon sSmith` :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea to "fiddle" with the loop counter is often ill-adviced. It definitely is for the job you want to do here. The canonic approach is using a flag. Rough outline:

```
int wasspace = 1; // to capitalize the *first* character
for (i=0; name[i]; ++i)
{
    printf("%c", wasspace ? toupper((unsigned char)name[i]) : name[i]);
    wasspace = (name[i] == ' ');
    // maybe better: wasspace = isspace((unsigned char)name[i]);
    // so you handle tabs, newlines etc. as well
}
```

---

On a side note, part of your problem was this line:

```
    if(i == ' ')
```

`i` is your loop counter, **not** the `i`'th character in your `name`. Comparing it to a space doesn't make sense.

Comment: What's the reason to use int and not bool?

Comment: @WernerHenze `bool` in C is IMHO only useful as additional *code documentation*, so if you like, you can replace `int wasspace` with `_Bool wasspace` here (or `bool wasspace` if you included `stdbool.h`). I personally don't use it, the result of all boolean operators in C is `int` anyways. Of course, in C++ it would be a different story.

Comment: @FelixPalmen -- I am mostly in agreement on you with this; it sometimes seems like more of a nuisance than anything else to use `stdbool.h`. But `_Bool` only needs to be wide enough to hold 0 and 1, so it may be narrower than an `int`. Maybe there are times when this serves as more than documentation. `_Bool` is 1 byte on my system.

Comment: @DavidBowling correct, and if I read the C standard correctly, it even **has** to have size 1. But then, `true` and `false` are `int` as well, so this is only relevant when storing a lot of boolean values, and you could achieve the same with `char` (although this might indeed look confusing) :)

Comment: @FelixPalmen -- Agree, the only use case I can imagine is for storing large numbers of boolean values. "It even **has** to have size 1": so it would appear. The rank of `_Bool` must be _less than_ the rank of `char` implying that the value range of `_Bool` is a subrange of `char`. Yet, I see no requirement that the _size_ of a type is connected to its conversion rank; consider [footnote 122, §6.7.2.1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note122): "While the number of bits in a `_Bool` object is at least `CHAR_BIT`, the width (number of sign and value bits) of a `_Bool` may be just 1 bit."

Comment: So a `_Bool` may contain padding bits making it larger than a `char`, I believe. I used "wide enough" sloppily in my first comment. Anyway, didn't mean to hijack your comments thread, just seemed like an interesting rabbit-hole ;)

Comment: @FelixPalmen This additional code documentation is exactly the benefit that I want, so I would use bool.

Comment: @WernerHenze that's nice, but as `bool` was only introduced in C later (C99) and all operators evaluate to `int` anyways, using `int` for flags became idiomatic C and a C coder will expect `int`s with names like "*is*", "*was*", "*has*", ... to be booleans. So well, it's finally a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fine opportunity to learn more about the other operators at your disposal - in this case "?:":

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
  {
  char name[100];

  printf("Value pls: \n");
  fgets(name, 100, stdin);

  for(int i = 0 ; i < strlen(name) ; ++i)
    printf("%c", (i == 0 || name[i-1] == ' ') ? toupper(name[i]) : name[i]);
  }
```

Best of luck.